# PHP OOP - toString not working

Tags: php, oop, tostring

I have this class:

```
<?php

class config {
    var $config="";
    public function __construct($d) {
        switch(strtolower(trim($d))) {
            case "sql":
            $this -> config = array(...); 
            break;
        }
    }

    public function toString() {
            return $this -> config;
    }
}
?>

$c = new config("sql");// calling the class
echo $c; //error
```

I'am getting the following error:

```
( ! ) Catchable fatal error: Object of class config could not be converted to string in ..
```

why not works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magic method name should be

```
public function __toString()
```

Even then, your `$config` property appears to be an array so you can't simply return that.